# Google SaleEvent Structure Data Not Showing on Google Search Result

Tags: google-schemas

I am using the saleEvent markup structure data for my pages i.e. in.couponbricks.com/goomo-coupons

But it is not showing on search result page of google.

When I check with site:in.couponbricks.com/goomo-coupons it shows perfectly. I also verified on google structured testing tool.

All my competitors (almost everyone) are using the same structure and for them working fine. I am trying this since last 6 month but I don't understand why it is not workign for me.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: You maybe find the answers in [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=ru#!topic/webmasters/LkQIcyq9Wb0;context-place=topicsearchin/webmasters/category$3Astructured-data%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) helpful, you have the same problem. Also check if your events is covered in the [Google's content guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/events#content-guidelines). Then, you have to consider the [technical guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/events#technical-guidelines) as well, so your event will show us rich card.

Comment: I checked the thread but unfortunately, this is not resolved discussion.